# tflite::MicroInterpreter::input returns a TfLiteTensor with data pointer set to nullptr

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tflite, tflm

While running a simple TfLiteMicro inference model on a Linux/x64 machine I am running into segfaults when trying to set input tensor or reading from output tensor. To summarize:

1. I can see the input and output tensors get allocated, the tensor pointers are valid and can be dereferenced (prior to calling `AllocateTensors()` they're set to `nullptr`).
2. Trying to dereference `data` pointer of a valid input/output tensor (however obtained) results in a segfault.
3. I've tried different models and different arena sizes, but nothing changes.
4. I can call `Invoke()` method of the interpreter without an issue (however, I'd expect it to segfault given that it probably accesses input/output tensors' data).

I've cloned the TfLiteMicro repository and ran the `make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile` to compile the shared library. I've built the final executable with:

```
g++ -o test.out test.cpp ../tflite-micro/gen/linux_x86_64_default/lib/libtensorflow-microlite.a -o test.out -I../tflite-micro/ -I/home/gstukelj/projects/plume/tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include -I../tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/gemmlowp/
```

Where `test.cpp` includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hw-float.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/core/c/common.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/system_setup.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"

int main(void) {

  tflite::InitializeTarget();

  const tflite::Model* model =
      ::tflite::GetModel(g_hello_world);

  TFLITE_CHECK_EQ(model->version(), TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION);

  static ::tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<4> op_resolver;

  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS(op_resolver.AddFullyConnected());
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS(op_resolver.AddSoftmax());
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS(op_resolver.AddReadVariable());
  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS(op_resolver.AddRelu());

  constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 60 * 1024;
  uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];

  tflite::MicroInterpreter interpreter(model, op_resolver, tensor_arena,
                                       kTensorArenaSize);

  if (interpreter.AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk) {
    printf("ERROR: AllocateTensors() failed\r\n");
  }
  printf("Tensors allocated\n");

  // If AllocateTensors() is skipped this will segfault
  TfLiteTensor* input = interpreter.input(0);

  printf("bytes == %ld\n", input->bytes);

  if (input == nullptr) {
    printf("input == nullptr\n");
  }

  if (input->dims == nullptr) {
    printf("input->dims == nullptr\n");
  }

  if (input->data.f == nullptr) {
    printf("input->data.f == nullptr\n");
  }

  if (input->data.data == nullptr) {
    printf("input->data.data == nullptr \n");
  }

  printf("input tensor type = %s\n", TfLiteTypeGetName(input->type));

  TF_LITE_ENSURE_STATUS(interpreter.Invoke());

  // // Either one of these two will segfault
  // float y_pred = interpreter.output(0)->data.f[0];
  // auto y_pred = interpreter.typed_output_tensor<float>(0)[0];

  return 0;
}
```

The output of running the executable is:

```
Tensors allocated
bytes == 4
input->dims == nullptr
input->data.f == nullptr
input->data.data == nullptr 
input tensor type = NOTYPE
```

I'm using the `hello_world` model from the TfLiteMicro repo, but when trying with a custom model at first, I've ran into the same issues, the only difference was that the `input->bytes` held a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by adding `#define TF_LITE_STATIC_MEMORY` at the top of the client source file. This was not TFLM specific issue. For more details see the discussion under [Valid pointer from static library code treated as a nullptr in the application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76598973/valid-pointer-from-static-library-code-treated-as-a-nullptr-in-the-application-c).