# Valid pointer from static library code treated as a nullptr in the application code

Tags: c++, linker, g++, static-libraries

I'm running a demo C++ application based on TensorFlow Lite Micro framework on Linux x64 machine. I've built the default library (actually an `ar` archive) and linked it against my demo app.

After some debugging I've noticed that the library code returns a valid data pointer directly to the application. If I try to dereference the pointer the application will segfault and indeed the application recognizes the data pointer as `nullptr`.

The library class method called from the application:

```
TfLiteTensor* MicroInterpreter::input(size_t index) {
  const size_t length = inputs_size();
  if (index >= length) {
    MicroPrintf("Input index %d out of range (length is %d)", index, length);
    return nullptr;
  }

  if (input_tensors_[index]->data.data == nullptr) {
    printf("returning null data pointer\n");
  }

  printf("returning data (idx = %ld) at %p\n", index, input_tensors_[index]->data.f);

  printf("data.f[0] == %f\n", (double)input_tensors_[index]->data.f[0]);
  input_tensors_[index]->data.f[0] = 5.f;
  printf("data.f[0] == %f\n", (double)input_tensors_[index]->data.f[0]);

  return input_tensors_[index];
}
```

The relevant part of the application code which calls the above library method directly:

```
  TfLiteTensor* input = interpreter.input(0);
  printf("received pointer at %p\n", input->data.f);
```

Output:

```
returning data (idx = 0) at 0x7ffe4c0f5a60
data.f[0] == 0.000000
data.f[0] == 5.000000
received pointer at (nil)
```

Meaning that the data pointer is valid and the memory pointed-to can be accessed, but only from the library code. As soon as I return that pointer to the application code it's suddenly treated as a `nullptr`.

I'm guessing the issue lies in how I'm linking the final executable, but I'm not sure what I got wrong. I've done it in two ways:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.out -I.../tflite-micro/ -I.../tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include -I.../tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/gemmlowp/ --std=c++17 -L.../tflite-micro/gen/linux_x86_64_default/lib/ -l:libtensorflow-microlite.a && ./test.out
```

and:

```
g++ test.cpp .../tflite-micro/gen/linux_x86_64_default/lib/libtensorflow-microlite.a -o test.out -I.../tflite-micro/ -I/home/gstukelj/projects/plume/tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers/include -I.../tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/downloads/gemmlowp/ --std=c++17 && ./test.out
```

I tried with adding `-static`, building the library with `-fpic`, building without `--std` flags or with different values, set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `.../tflite-micro/gen/linux_x86_64_default/lib/`, but it didn't change a thing.

The toolchain and kernel/distro used:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

5.15.0-76-generic #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
```

EDIT:

I've checked and printed out the value of `input_tensors_[index]` returned from the library code as well and it's the same for both library and application:

```
returning data (idx = 0) at 0x7ffd524366b0
returning tensor (idx = 0) at 0x7ffd5243e260
data.f[0] == 0.000000
data.f[0] == 5.000000
received data pointer at (nil)
received tensor pointer at 0x7ffd5243e260
```

If I call the same library method again I can see the data pointer remains valid beyond the point at which it's treated as a `nullptr` in the application code:

```
  TfLiteTensor* input = interpreter.input(0);

  printf("received data pointer at %px\n", input->data.f);
  printf("received tensor pointer at %px\n", input);

  TfLiteTensor* input2 = interpreter.input(0);

  printf("received data pointer at %px\n", input2->data.f);
  printf("received tensor pointer at %px\n", input2);
```

output:

```
returning data (idx = 0) at 0x7fffec3695c0
returning tensor (idx = 0) at 0x7fffec371170
data.f[0] == 0.000000
data.f[0] == 5.000000
received data pointer at (nil)
received tensor pointer at 0x7fffec371170
returning data (idx = 0) at 0x7fffec3695c0
returning tensor (idx = 0) at 0x7fffec371170
data.f[0] == 5.000000
data.f[0] == 5.000000
received data pointer at (nil)
received tensor pointer at 0x7fffec371170
```

Comment: OT: But please don't use `printf` in C++ programs. It's much too easy to cause *undefined behavior* using the type unsafe `printf` function compared to C++ streams and the `<<` stream insertion operator. For example using the invalid `%ld` format for a `size_t` value (it requires a `%zu` format specifier). Or other mistakes like mistaking the plain `%p` format as `%px`. Mistakes like that would not happen with `std::cout` and `<<`.

Comment: Also OT: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do with `(double) input_tensors_[index]->data.f[0]`) you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. In this case, the "wrong" that you're doing is the cast itself. If `input_tensors_[index]->data.f[0]` is a `float` then it will automatically be *promoted* to a `double` as an argument to a C-style vararg function (like `printf`). This cast is of course also not needed when using `std::cout` and `<<`.

Comment: The value you return is `input_tensors_[index]`, but you never check or print that value in the library code. You always just follow the pointer and assume it was valid. That's probably not the core problem, but it's a glaring mismatch

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the input. As you can probably tell I'm a simple man and I stick to C whenever possible. Just wanted to point out that automatic promoting doesn't fly with `-Wno-double-promotion`, removing it results in `tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.cc:296:62: error: implicit conversion from ‘float’ to ‘double’ when passing argument to function [-Werror=double-promotion]`.

Comment: @Useless `input_tensors_[index]` is a valid pointer both in application and library code. This should be also obvious from the cleaned-up code I've posted in the question. It's dereferenced in multiple `printf`s.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't crash tells me nothing at all about whether it's valid. For all I know `input_tensors_` is on the stack and is getting smashed due to a bug elsewhere.

Comment: @Useless Right, that's a good point, thanks! In that case I should look into the library code again.

Comment: @Useless The pointer is valid at least for the relevant duration. See the new edits to the question. If I call the method from the library for a second time, I can see that the pointers remain the same and can be derefenced in the library code, but not in the application code.

Comment: *If I try to dereference the pointer the application will segfault and indeed the application recognizes the data pointer as nullptr.* -- Just because the pointer looks valid doesn't mean it is. -- *I can see that the pointers remain the same* -- Dereferencing a pointer that has been trashed is undefined behavior.  Again, just because the pointer looks valid doesn't mean it's valid.  For example: `int *p = new int; delete p; std::cout << *p;` -- even though `p` **may** have the pointer value returned by `new` previously, thus looks valid, is UB when attempting to use it in `std::cout`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can dereference it in the library code before *and after* it’s treated as a nullptr in the application code. Please read the question in full, including the edit at the end.

Comment: *If I try to dereference the pointer the application will segfault* -- that is evidence that the pointer is invalid.  It doesn't matter what you are doing with it or what you are observing by issuing printf's.  The mere fact that dereferencing it and things blowing up indicates the pointer is not valid.  I'll ask you -- why would a pointer that is claimed to be valid act this way?  I doubt that the pointer lost its way by simply returning it from the library code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know the pointer is invalid, it also compares true to nullptr. You’re taking my sentences out of context and I have a feeling you have not really read the question or made the effort to understand it. Not that you’re in any way obliged to do so, but I just don’t understand what’s the point of your comments.

Comment: See @Useless comments on proving the validity of a pointer.  It can't be done by using `printf` statements.  The second thing is `MicroInterpreter::input` -- if the function is a non-static member function, but `MicroInterpeter` is not a valid object instance, then the entire function is invalid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie See my question and read it. I *dereference* it again in library code *after* it compares true to nullptr in the application code. Not relying on printf.

Comment: I would guess ODR violation. The library code and the executable code don't agree where - at which offset - `f` is located within `data`. Try printing `&data.f`, inside and outside. Or perhaps where `data` is located within `*input`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That must be it! If I return the `data.f` pointer directly I can dereference it in the application (read/write) without a problem. As you can probably tell, I'm not really verse in C++, but I'm guessing the issue is then in the way I compile the application source/source file itself, rather than in the way it is linked to the library? Any pointers at what should I look at? Feel free to provide this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It must be the disagreement on the offset of `data` w.r.t. to `input` as `data` is an union, and I'm guessing `data.f` should be the same pointer as just `data`.

Comment: Have you built `libtensorflow-microlite.a` yourself, with the same compiler and options that you are using to build `test.cpp`? Or have you gotten a pre-built binary somewhere?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I built the lib from source via provided `Makefile` and then I built the final binary with my native toolchain, so almost certainly the tools/settings are not the same. Would this be a hard requirement? Because for my actual use-case I'll be definitely using different toolchains (the plan is to provide a wrapper around this lib and provide it all as a relocatable binary with a C code facing API, so that I can link it to existing C project using a C compiler).

Comment: Depends on whether the library config changes the layout of the objects it passes across the interface. You can just look in the headers to see if anything uses obvious conditional compilation. Otherwise you can modify the library to print a load of `sizeof` and `offsetof` values for these structures until you see where it disagrees with your client code

Comment: @Useless That was another great advice, thanks! Indeed there was a conditional compilation for the C(!) struct `TfLiteTensor`, making sure the same definition gets pulled in from the header included by the application code resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue was in ODR (One Definition Rule) violation. There were two definitions of the `struct TfLiteTensor` in the header file included in both the library code and client code, conditioned by an `#ifdef`. Making sure the same macro is defined in the client code as the one used by the library resolved the issue.